# How to upgrade package.json in angular2

Tags: angular

While uploading to production it says the error @angular/common does not satisfy its sybling

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"events": "^1.0.2",
"fbjs": "^0.3.1",
"flux": "^2.1.1",
"ng2-toastr": "^0.3.1",
"ng2-tooltip": "0.0.2",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
```

can someone please hrlp me.......

Answer (score 0):

Now angular RC6 is released and you can update your package.json with below two steps :

- Manually from [quick start repository](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/tree/3b7452cc444c49c139ea39523ced0468c2362c16) of angular
- By following steps as per [RC4 to RC5 Migration](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html) which will also update to rc6